# Physical storage of kernel data

Tags: kernel, ram

I have some question about physical storage of the kernel data in Linux, I know that the upper 1 GB of the VIRTUAL memory of each process points to the same PHYSICAL location, but

1. Does this piece of the data has to be contiguous in PHYSICAL media as in VIRTUAL MEMORY?
2. Does kernel data will take ONLY 1 GB of the PHYSICAL memory?
3. Can some pages of the kernel data be swapped to the disk (for example page tables, page global directory is always in physical memory and can't be swapped to disk as I understand)
4. What is the point of dividing a 32 bit VIRTUAL address into two levels (level of page global directory - 10 bit, and second of page table - 10 bit) and offset 12 bit, if it is not pageable what are the advantages of those two levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, it does not have to be contiguous.  Any virtual page can be mapped to any physical page.
2. For the most part, yes, the kernel memory is limited to 1 GB, but the page cache can grow larger than that because only a small bit of it must be mapped into the kernel address space at a time.
3. Kernel memory is non pagable.

Note that this applies to the 32 bit kernel only.

Comment: thank You for the answer, about 3, what is the point to divide 32 bit VIRTUAL address into two levels (level of page global directory - 10 bit, and second of page table - 10 bit) and offset 12 bit, if it is not pagable what are the advantages of those two levels?

Comment: @maicon, the processor does that to allow the kernel to map virtual memory to physical memory in any way it likes.  Whether it can swap those pages out to disk or not, and which ones it is willing to do so with is entirely up to the kernel.  Linux chose not to allow any kernel memory to be paged out rather than try to keep track of what kernel pages are safe to swap or not ( can't swap out pages needed to do the disk IO to swap them back in ).  It is split into multiple levels to allow the kernel to be able to swap out the page tables themselves, or to simply omit chunks of the page table.